# Creating an exchange 2010 inbox rule

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, inbox

I've an Exchange 2010, how can I create a rule and apply it to all users.

The rule must create a folder in each inbox and put the read and delivered notification messages that specified folder.

Answer (score -1):

You need a [Managed Folder Mailbox Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996035%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx). Something like:

```
New-ManagedFolder -Name "New Folder" -FolderName "New Folder" –DefaultFolderType ManagedCustomFolder 

New-ManagedContentSettings -FolderName "Entire Mailbox" -MessageClass REPORT.IPM.NOTE.IPNRN -Name MoveReceipt -RetentionAction MoveToFolder "New Folder"
```

Comment: can I use the MessageClass in creating a rule to MarkAsRead the read and delivered notification messages?